# Get substring from MemoryStream without converting entire stream to string

Tags: c#, substring, string-matching, memorystream

I would like to be able to efficiently get a substring from a MemoryStream (that originally comes from a xml file in a zip). Currently, I read the entire MemoryStream to a string and then search for the start and end tags of the xml node I desire. This works fine but the text file may be very large so I would like to avoid converting the entire MemoryStream into a string and instead just extract the desired section of xml text directly from the stream.

What is the best way to go about this?

```
string xmlText;
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName))
{
    var ze = zip[zipPath];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ze.Extract(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            xmlText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}

string startTag = "<someTag>";
string endTag = "</someTag>";
int startIndex = xmlText.IndexOf(startTag, StringComparison.Ordinal);
int endIndex = xmlText.IndexOf(endTag, startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) + endTag.Length - 1;
xmlText = xmlText.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1);
```

Comment: You could create a `XmlReader` from the memory stream to avoid loading the entire file to memory.

Comment: @juharr: Write that up as the answer. The other way is going to be a royal pain and probably not work right.

Comment: what zip library is that? Your current method extracts the whole file into MemoryStream, so it can result in out of memory exception for big files. In .NET 4.5 [`ZipArchiveEntry.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open) can be used to [stream the file](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/974/zip-archives-csharp-dotnet)

Comment: It is DotNetZip. I need to use .NET 4.0.

Comment: seems like you can use [`ZipEntry.OpenReader`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/4ef6405c-33ff-a8aa-1731-def3ec5cac24.htm) instead of `.Extract` and then use `XmlReader.Create` on that stream instead of the MemoryStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is a valid xml file then you should be able to use a `XmlReader` to avoid loading the entire file into memory

```
string xmlText;
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileName))
{
    var ze = zip[zipPath];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ze.Extract(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        using (var xml = XmlReader.Create(ms))
        {
            if(xml.ReadToFollowing("someTag"))
            {
                xmlText = xml.ReadInnerXml();
            }
            else
            {
                // <someTag> not found
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll likely want to catch potential exceptions if the file is not valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that since it is xml it will have line breaks, it would probably be best to use StreamReader ReadLine and search for your tags in each line.  (Also note put your StreamReader in a using as well.)

Something like

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ze.Extract(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                bool adding = false;
                string startTag = "<someTag>";
                string endTag = "</someTag>";
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string tmp = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (!adding && tmp.Contains(startTag))
                    {
                        adding = true;
                    }
                    if (adding)
                    {
                        text.Append(tmp);
                    }
                    if (tmp.Contains(endTag))
                        break;
                }
                xmlText = text.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This assumes that the start and end tags are on a line by themselves.  If not, you could clean up the resulting text string by getting the index of start and end again like you originally did.